# Turn rectangular UIImageView into a circle

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cornerradius

My ViewController has an UIImageView (lets name it img) as atribute, and in the beginning, it shows img in full screen, that is, its size is a rectangle similar to the ViewController bounds.

I'd like to do an animation with img, making it become a little circle (not just a rectangle with circular corners) and then move it to some corner of the ViewController.

How can I achieve this? I prefer not to send any code cos Im pretty sure I did it the wrong way (I tried to turn it into a square and then set a cornerRadius (with radius width/2), then making scale and translating position at once, but its a mess and works wrongly, so lets forget it)

Comment: take imageView with Same  Height and Width, and set its layer property : imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = img.frame.size.height / 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution sounds fine to me, but what might be going wrong, is the fact that animating corner radius is not supported by UIView.animateWithDuration as seen in the [View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1).  Therefor, the results are sometimes not whats expected.

You can try out the following code.

```
func animate() {

    //Some properties that needs to be set on UIImageView
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill

    //Create animations
    let cornerRadiusAnim = changeCornerRadiusAnimation()
    let squareAnim = makeSquareAnimation()
    let boundsAnim = changeBoundsAnimation()
    let positionAnim = changePositionAnimation(CGPointMake(300,480))

    //Use group for sequenced execution of animations
    let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    animationGroup.animations = [cornerRadiusAnim, squareAnim, boundsAnim, positionAnim]
    animationGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animationGroup.removedOnCompletion = false
    animationGroup.duration = positionAnim.beginTime + positionAnim.duration
    imageView.layer.addAnimation(animationGroup, forKey: nil)

}

func makeSquareAnimation() -> CABasicAnimation {

    let center = imageView.center
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"bounds")
    animation.duration = 0.1;
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGRect: imageView.frame)
    animation.toValue = NSValue(CGRect: CGRectMake(center.x,center.y,imageView.frame.width,imageView.frame.width))
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false
    return animation

}

func changeBoundsAnimation() -> CABasicAnimation {

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"transform.scale")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.fromValue = imageView.layer.mask?.valueForKeyPath("transform.scale")
    animation.toValue = 0.1
    animation.duration = 0.5
    animation.beginTime = 0.1
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false
    return animation

}

func changeCornerRadiusAnimation() -> CABasicAnimation {

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"cornerRadius")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = imageView.frame.size.width * 0.5
    animation.duration = 0.1
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false
    return animation

}

func changePositionAnimation(newPosition: CGPoint) -> CABasicAnimation {

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.fromValue =  NSValue(CGPoint: imageView.layer.position)
    animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: newPosition)
    animation.duration = 0.3
    animation.beginTime = 0.6
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false
    return animation
}
```

Comment: omg i don't know if i was supposed to say that here but i love you

Comment: @Daniel happy I could help

Answer (score 0):

// try like this, i hope it will work for you.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in

      img.layer.masksToBounds = true
       img.layer.cornerRadius = img.frame.size.height / 2 // here img must be in square shape (height == width) 

        }) { (finished : Bool) -> Void in

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**option 1** call below method from code

```
// UIimageView Circle
class func roundImageView(imageView:UIImageView){
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    //imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

**option 2** make user defined run time attributes from storyboard

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```